In HTTP2,Whether MAGIC can be followed by settings_ack
from 3.5.  HTTP/2 Connection Preface in HTTP/2 protocol
   That is, the connection preface starts with the string "PRI *
   HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\nSM\r\n\r\n").  This sequence MUST be followed by a
   SETTINGS frame (Section 6.5), which MAY be empty. 

In this context,  does it imply that the SETTINGS frame sent by the client following the connection preface should be its own SETTINGS frame rather than an acknowledgment (ACK) of the SETTINGS frame sent by the server?
or say whether MAGIC (the connection preface) can be followed by settings_ack?thanks!

The SETTINGS frame sent by the client after the preface is the client's SETTINGS frame, not the reply to the server's.
The RFC details that the "magic" bytes PRI * HTTP/2.0\r\nSM\r\n are the start of the client preface.
The whole client preface is the "magic" bytes plus the client's SETTINGS frame.
This is repeated in the SETTINGS frame section, where it says:

A SETTINGS frame MUST be sent by both endpoints at the start of a connection

